# How can EditText returns users name in via Toast message when they write it in?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-toast

I am creating a simple quiz app and I need when users put their name in the EditText pop up a Toast message said `"GoodLuck"+ Name`.Could someone help on this? Here is my code:
    Thanks a lot!

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        String Name;
        int score = 0;
        Button submitButton;
        Button resetButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //user input name
             final EditText nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameField);
              Name = nameField.getText().toString();

            //submitButton shows user score
            submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    submitButton.setText("Your score is:" + score);
                }
            });
            //resetButton reset score to 0
            resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
            resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    submitButton.setText((String.valueOf(0)));
                }
            });
        }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:textColor="#EF6C00"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

Comment: Immediately after they enter name or after submit button is clicked?

Comment: immediately after they put their name

Comment: How to know if the user have finish writing the name. At least there should be a button to mark the "Finish"

Comment: I suggest you to keep one button to update Name. otherwise it is not possible to know whether user completed entering name.

Comment: Ya you are right!I ll try it by adding a new button. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

User should press **Enter** button after finsihed typing his name.

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getKeyCode() ==       KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good Luck:"+editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                    return false;
                } 

            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you dont want to force user to press **Enter** button. Then use one button to updte name. Once user click on the button you can popup Toast.

Comment: if you press enter key then it will go to next line of that edittext... dont it?

Comment: No if use this android:singleLine="true" it will not go to next line.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in submit button click

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GoodLuck " +Name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```